# Double integral with the whole part

Tags: integration

Calculate 
$\iint_D\sqrt{\left\lfloor x^3-y\right\rfloor}$
where $D$ the area is limited with $y=0,y=2,y=|x|^3$.

I dont't know how to begin.

Comment: For $y=1$, $|x|\leq 1$ and $\lfloor x^3-y\rfloor$ is negative and the squareroot is not defined. Is the statement of the problem correct?